# Return type is not assignable

Tags: node.js, typescript

A 3rd party package has a function that looks like this...

```
function asKey(key: KeyObject | KeyInput, parameters?: KeyParameters): RSAKey | ECKey | OKPKey | OctKey;
```

All of the return types (`RSAKey | ECKey | OKPKey | OctKey`) are interfaces that extend `Key`.

I am using the `asKey` function and trying to set a return type of `RSAKey` because I know it only ever returns this 1 interface...

```
private foo = (): RSAKey => {
    return asKey('foo');
};
```

However this fails with the following:

```
Type 'RSAKey | ECKey | OKPKey | OctKey' is not assignable to type 'RSAKey'.
  Type 'ECKey' is not assignable to type 'RSAKey'.
    Types of property 'kty' are incompatible.
      Type '"EC"' is not assignable to type '"RSA"'.ts(2322)
```

If I change my return type to `Key` in my foo function I get no errors, but thats not what I want because RSAKey has an extra function I want to call that is not in Key. How can I best get this return type working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are writing the following code

```
private foo = (): RSAKey => {
    return asKey('foo');
};
```

Typescript is looking at `asKey` and see that there could be multiple different type that can be returned, and `foo` doesn't handle them, that's why you get an error.

If you know that `askey` will returns only a `RSAKey` type, you have to tell typescript:

> It's ok, I know what's going on. Trust me, the type is RSAKey

And you do that using the keyword `as`

```
private foo = (): RSAKey => {
    return asKey('foo') as RSAKey;
};
```